# Graph generation from a non-paired edge list

Tags: graphs-and-networks

The elements in

```
e = {{6414, 6598, 6927}, {7, 1035, 2382, 6927}, …}
```

are the graph nodes; for example, `{6414,6598,6927}` is equivalent to the two pairs, `{6414, 6598}` and `{6598, 6927}`. I wanted to know if a `Graph` object can take non-paired edge list format as in the original `e`. If not I can convert each edge element into a pair-format by using `Partition`, i.e. `Partition[e, 2, 1]`.

Comment: @Szabolcs is correct.  I now see that your matrix e is (likely) not an adjacency list.  So what **does** your list e represent?  Can you craft a teeny, illustrative example?  What does 6414 in the matrix represent?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that your matrix is a weighted adjacency matrix.

```
 WeightedAdjacencyGraph[mywts = Table[RandomReal[], {4}, {4}], 
 VertexLabels -> "Name",
 EdgeLabels -> 
  Table[Rule[EdgeList[mygraph][[i]], Flatten[mywts][[i]]], {i, 16}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[`Thread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Thread.html) is useful for converting this format to a simple edge list.

Example:

```
Thread[ 1 <-> {2,3,4} ]

(* {1 <-> 2, 1 <-> 3, 1 <-> 4} *)
```

Using this idea, you could do

```
Graph@Catenate[Thread[First[#] <-> Rest[#]] & /@ e]
```

For Mathematica versions earlier than 10, use `Flatten[..., 1]` in place of `Catenate[...]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
e = {{6414, 6598, 6927}, {7, 1035, 2382, 6927}};
```

#### BlockMap

```
Graph[Join @@ (BlockMap[DirectedEdge @@ # &, #, 2, 1] & /@ e), 
    VertexShapeFunction -> "Name"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

#### Partition

Using the undocumented 6-argument form of `Partition`:

```
Graph[Join @@ (Partition[#, 2, 1, {1, -1}, {}, DirectedEdge] & /@ e), 
  VertexShapeFunction -> "Name"]
```

> same picture

#### PathGraph + GraphUnion

```
 GraphUnion @@ (PathGraph[#, DirectedEdges -> True] & /@ e);
 SetProperty[%, VertexShapeFunction -> "Name"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]